# Do I need to close http CloudTasksClient in Google Cloud?

Tags: http, google-app-engine, php-7, gcloud, google-cloud-tasks

I'm setting up Google Cloud Tasks with PHP via http and can't understand do I need to close the connection or not?

There are two places I'm looking:

1) [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks)

```
$client = new CloudTasksClient();
$queueName = $client->queueName($projectId, $locationId, $queueId);

$httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
$httpRequest->setUrl($url);
$httpRequest->setHttpMethod(HttpMethod::POST);
$task = new Task();
$task->setHttpRequest($httpRequest);
$response = $client->createTask($queueName, $task);
```

2) [Gcloud Client Library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.105.0/tasks%2Fv2beta3%2Fgapic%2Fcloudtasksgapicclient?method=createTask)

```
$cloudTasksClient = new CloudTasksClient();
try {
    $formattedParent = $cloudTasksClient->queueName('[PROJECT]', '[LOCATION]', '[QUEUE]');
    $task = new Task();
    $response = $cloudTasksClient->createTask($formattedParent, $task);
} finally {
    $cloudTasksClient->close();
}
```

**My version:**

```
$client = new CloudTasksClient();
try{
    $queueName = $client->queueName($projectId, $locationId, $queueId);
    $httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
    $httpRequest->setUrl($url);
    $httpRequest->setHttpMethod(HttpMethod::POST);
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setHttpRequest($httpRequest);
    $response = $client->createTask($queueName, $task);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $this->logError("Error");
}
finally {
    $client->close();  <-- ???????? ( Do I need this )
}
```

I'm using App Engine, if it makes any difference.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with PHP but... as inferred by your question, there's no service-side behavior from the `close()`. You're not opening a stateful connection to Cloud Tasks. I've used the SDKs with most of the other languages and none of these -- to my knowledge -- has a dispose|close method. It may be that it's included in PHP (and in the docs) because it's recommended for efficient memory management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a close() statement is to gracefully wrap up the connection resource, such as flushing pending data and freeing memory.

In review of the code, `close()` seems to do the following:

- Gracefully clean up in-progress RPC calls
- Release some memory resources
- Does not currently appear to have an effect on REST calls
- Create a space for future, Cloud Tasks-specific teardown activities

As a best practice, it should be done. However, if your PHP script is pretty focused on the Cloud Tasks interaction it appears to have limited impact.

#### Traversing the code

Looking at the [Cloud Tasks client code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/v0.105.0/Tasks/src/V2beta3/Gapic/CloudTasksGapicClient.php), it appears the close method is defined in the [GapicClientTrait](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-php/blob/master/src/GapicClientTrait.php).

It turns out this statement is a passthru to the transport:

```php
    /**
     * Initiates an orderly shutdown in which preexisting calls continue but new
     * calls are immediately cancelled.
     *
     * @experimental
     */
    public function close()
    {
        $this->transport->close();
    }
```

The [code for available transports](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-php/tree/master/src/Transport) has options for REST and gRPC.

Following REST to the [HttpUnaryTransportTrait](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-php/blob/master/src/Transport/HttpUnaryTransportTrait.php), this appears to be a no-op:

```php
    public function close()
    {
        // Nothing to do.
    }
```

Following gRPC to Grpc\BaseStub we reach the [gRPC client implementation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/php/lib/Grpc/BaseStub.php).